# Previously working docker now having errors

Tags: macos, docker

I have been testing docker with no issues but suddenly my connection(?) seems to have dropped.

Has anyone experienced this?

What is the fix?

```
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/


exit status 255
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

Unexpected error getting machine url: exit status 255
%USER%s-MacBook-Pro:~ %USER%$ docker run hello-world
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
%USER%s-MacBook-Pro:~ %USER%$
```

I have been launching docker from the docker quickstart terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mac OS, I use this command to resolve the issue

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Comment: this seems much more useful than my answer.

Comment: that gives me `Unexpected error getting machine url: exit status 255`

Answer (score 0):

Killing some processes that had things like "docker" in the name and then rebooting the terminal solver the issue for me. Unsure how I created the issue therefore tough to duplicate.

Comment: Can you accept your answer if it solved it so that your question no longer shows as "Unanswered"?

Comment: @AndyShinn Unsure if you're new to SO but you cannot accept your answer until 2 days after you post your question! Will happily once the proper amount of time passes.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you are using 64 bit Windos os, For me it was because visualization was not enabled in my bios. Enabled it and issue was resolved.

I could see “this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot” error in virtual box screen

1. restart system and go to bios
2. security>virtualization>enable>save and exit
3. in virtual box, setings>general>basic : check if 64 bit linux is selected

Good luck